# Reading a resource file in Jar

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, kotlin, embedded-resource

I am using IntelliJ Idea and trying to read a json file from the resources folder in the project structure. I read the json file and return the contents using jackson.

```
return mapper.readValue(File("src/main/resources/file.json"), Map::class.java)
```

As soon i build the project and make a jar it throws me an error it cannot find the file. I looked here a bit and found that i should use ClassLoader to read files from the resources folder. So i do this now -

```
mapper.readValue(File( ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource("src/main/resources/file.json").toURI()), Map::class.java)
```

Now I get a NullPointerException. I am a bit lost now. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: You cannot read a file inside a jar as a normal text file, as per:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389255/reading-a-resource-file-from-within-jar

Comment: What is `mapper`? Is it an [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html)?

Comment: @AndrewThompson - yes it is an ObjectMapper.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your build follows the default convention, whatever under `src/main/resource` will be available on the **root** of the classpath, so you just need to change the code to:

```
mapper.readValue(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("file.json"), Map::class.java)
```

Comment: somehow doesnt work. throws an error stating - No content to map due to end-of-input\n at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: 1, column: 0. I tried the same with getResource instead of getResourceAsStream as well but that fails as well

Comment: the getResource("file.json").file throws the following error - ClassLoader.getSystemCla…Resource(\"file.json\") must not be null

Comment: The path to the resource is more likely `/main/resources/file.json` but only you could know for sure.

Comment: under the root - the file is under src/main/resources/metadata.json

Comment: Ok for clarification - Whenever i have a file to read in the src/main/resource folder after build(using Gradle) does it always goes to the root? can this not be changed somehow?

Comment: Ok. strange but this works somehow - `mapper.readValue(javaClass.classLoader.getResource("file.json"), Map::class.java)`